# Tensorflow + gemmlowp using cross-compile with contrib/makefile?

Tags: tensorflow, cross-compiling

I'm able to cross-compile for my platform by modifying contrib/makefile/Makefile.  It works great!

How do I get the quantized elements into what gets built?  I see it is included as a dependency to get fetched, but I don't see the quantized elements actually getting built.

Is the process for using a quantized network on a cross-compiled target to load an example network and convert to a quantized network (and optimize dequantize/quantize operations) on the host with python, and then save that off for use in the benchmark on target?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was as easy as adding all the .cc files from the contrib/quantization directory into tf_cc_files.txt!

Make sure the quantized network was built with a tensorflow version that matches what you've built.